# margin-left:auto; into div tag

Tags: html, css, margin

does not work margin-left:auto; my html code is:

```
<body>
 <div id='maindiv'>
    <div id='logout'>Logout</div> 
    <div id='Mcontrol'>Menu Control</div>
 </div>
<script src='control/myjs.js' language='javascript' /> </script>
</body>
```

and here is my CSS code:

```
#logout{
  margin-left:auto;
  font-family:arial;font-size:12px;
       }
#logout:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
       }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Please clarify your question.

Comment: but where to set `logout`? What is question ?

Comment: in this example does not work margin-left:auto; :)

Comment: What do you expect `margin-left: auto` to do?

Comment: i want this logout word moves in end of left side :?.

Comment: Actually, What's the Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you exactly want, but I think that you want to have the log-out button in the center of the page?

If yes; check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sysBM/

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/rJYCk/)

It is not clear from your explanation but may be this is what you want.